# Citing statistical information presented in a table using data from a variety of sources?

Tags: citations, tables

How do I cite information that I am presenting in a table (i.e. that I have created), when the statistics I have compiled are from different sources?

Comment: As it stands, the question is a bit unclear. Could you make an example table?

Comment: Questions about formatting of statistics are [off-topic on Academia.SE](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/are-questions-about-formatting-and-presenting-results-off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to citations with reference to a table, I often see it implemented in the APA-style, that is:

- table heading *above* the table
- in the table text, there are small letters in superscript (a, b, c...)
- the references are named *below* the table, again with the small letters in superscript, but all in one line

I found this example in the [APA Style Blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2016/06/navigating-copyright-how-to-cite-sources-in-a-table.html):

[image: Citations in a table]

---

In addition, that blog post offers a different example in which the respective references are placed in their own column:

[image: Table with references in a specific column]